# Can't read any data from mysql table but I can insert into it

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am using python mysql.connector and I am able to insert into the table, and check it through DBeaver(database manager) and verify the data commits. However, if I ever try to read/SELECT from the table, I get 'None'. I'm  not sure what I can do from here.

My code:

```
import mysql.connector, config

# declare vars
cfg = config.Setting(config.argparser())
sql_username = cfg.get_setting('sql', 'username')
sql_password = cfg.get_setting('sql', 'password')
sql_host = cfg.get_setting('sql', 'host')
sql_db = cfg.get_setting('sql', 'db')
db_config = mysql.connector.connect(user=sql_username, password=sql_password, host=sql_host, database=sql_db)
cursor = db_config.cursor(buffered=True)
print(cursor.execute('SELECT "date_created", "date_due", "title", "completed"'
               'FROM remind;'))


# query function, checks for errors, returns result of query
# columns: id | date_created | date_due | title | completed
#
def insert(db_id: object, db_table: object, date_created: object, date_due: object, title: object,
           completed: object) -> object:
    try:
        stmt = ("INSERT INTO " + db_table +
                "(id, date_created, date_due, title, completed) "
                "VALUES (%(id)s, %(date_created)s, %(date_due)s, %(title)s, %(completed)s)")
        data = {
            'id': db_id,
            'date_created': date_created,
            'date_due': date_due,
            'title': title,
            'completed': completed
        }
        query_result = cursor.execute(stmt, data)
        db_config.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        query_result = ("Insert Query: Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
    return query_result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.execute()` will execute the select query. The return type is None implying that **execution passed**.

If you want to see the results, try `cursor.fetchall()`. That fetches all the rows in result set.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT "date_created", "date_due", "title", "completed"'
               'FROM remind;')
resultSet = cursor.fetchall()
for row in resultSet:
    print(row)
```